# Simple sort algortihm not working - Index issues

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I am trying to sort an array using an algorithm, but I am having trouble with my index.

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim List() As Integer = {9, 8, 5, 6}
    Dim InnerPointer As Integer = 0
    Dim CurrentValue As Integer
    For OutPointer = 1 To List.Length - 1
        CurrentValue = List(OutPointer)
        While InnerPointer > 0 And List(InnerPointer) > CurrentValue
            List(InnerPointer + 1) = List(InnerPointer)
            InnerPointer = InnerPointer - 1
        End While
        List(InnerPointer + 1) = CurrentValue
    Next
    For Each element In List
        Console.WriteLine(element)
    Next
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

I define InnerPointer as 0 because my array is 0 index based, but this means my While Loop wont kick in...and yet I do want to compare index 0 with index 1 to determine which number is bigger. I cant for the life of me work out where the logical fallacy is

Comment: So change it to `>= 0` then.

Comment: @jimcilhinney - that would cause an index out of range exception

Comment: Either your algorithm is wrong or your implementation of the algorithm is wrong. How are we supposed to know which if we don't know what the algorithm is? Do what you should have done in the first place. Write out the algorithm in words and then step through your code and, at each step, compare your code to the algorithm to make sure that it's doing what it's supposed to be doing. If it always is then the algorithm is wrong.